# Why can we assume a ctm of ZFC exists in forcing

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, forcing, independence-results

Following Kunen's book, it makes clear that countable transitive models (ctm) exist only for a finite list of axioms of ZFC. So, why can we assume a ctm of the whole ZFC axioms exists and use it as our ground model? At the beginning of chapter VII, Kunen says that the formal proof is done by contraposition (assume ZFC+\neg CH is not consistent and show that ZFC is not consistent) but we can just "assume naively that we have a countable transitive M satisfying all of ZFC". I don't understand this point.

Comment: I am not an expert in these areas, but a ctm of $ZFC$ (or indeed any model of $ZFC$) proves the consistency of $ZFC$, which isn't provable in $ZFC$ (if it's consistent). Consequently the existence of a ctm of $ZFC$ isn't provable in $ZFC$ and must be taken as an additional assumption. Note that $ZFC$ proves the consistency of all finite fragments of its axiomatization, so it does prove the existence of models for all finite fragments of itself so these models need not be additional assumptions (axioms) in the theory.

Comment: TL;DR we can't, and usually we don't. It is a useful device, especially when first introducing forcing, but it is not strictly necessary - usually we take some finite fragment of ZFC, or, as I believe Cohen originally did, you can develop forcing in a purely syntactic way and avoid models altogether.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57225/kunens-use-of-countable-transitive-models, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414971/philosophy-of-forcing-and-ctm, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244214/why-do-we-need-a-transitive-model-in-forcing-arguments, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364431/which-is-the-more-popular-approach-to-forcing-in-the-literature

Comment: Add a constant symbol $M$ to the language of set theory and augment ZFC with the relativizations of its axioms to $M$ plus the one additional statement that $M$ is countable and transitive. You already know that if ZFC is consistent then so is any finite fragment of this theory. Therefore this whole theory is consistent if ZFC is.

Comment: Also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88134/formal-proof-of-conzfc-conzfc-not-ch-in-zfc

Comment: @NikWeaver Would we need to augment ZFC with an additional $\in_M$ relation symbol for membership in $M$ as well, and assert that it modeled $ZFC$ using this internal membership’? If the model is countable and transitive it can’t have external membership and model $ZFC$ or else it would externally prove that it contained uncountably many sets, correct? Or can we just assert the existence of an internal membership relation on $M$ modeling $ZFC$ without adding a specific relation symbol for it?

Comment: @AlecRhea No additional symbol is needed. Maybe phrasing things this way will help: "The $\{\in,c\}$-theory $T$ consisting of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + '$c$ is a countable transitive set' + $\{\varphi^c: \varphi\in\mathsf{ZFC}\}$ is a conservative extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}$." Note that in a model of $T$, the "$\in$ of $c$" is just $\in\upharpoonright c^2$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber But is membership in a model of $T$ external membership? My confusion essentially stems from my (potentially wrong) understanding that any countable model $M$ of $ZFC$  in some background set theory $T$ with external membership $\in$ had to have a separate 'internal membership' $\in_M\subseteq M\times M$ that thinks $M$ has uncountably many elements, while $\in$ can see that $M$ is really just countable. Is it possible to have a standard countable model of $ZFC$, that is a model where membership is external membership and the model is countable externally?

Comment: @AlecRhea "Is it possible to have a standard countable model of , that is a model where membership is external membership and the model is countable externally?" Yes, it is (under reasonable hypotheses of course). I think you're misunderstanding something here. The whole point of a countable transitive model is that its elementhood relation is exactly $\in$. The **powersethood relation** will be different, but that's separate.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Interesting, thank you -- so we can have a model where membership is standard membership but the powerset operation is still interpreted differently than we do externally, is this because the subsets allowed in the model may differ from the subsets that exist externally (that is, we have that for $x\in M$, $\mathcal{P}^M(x)\subset\mathcal{P}(x)$)? (if this is too basic feel free to shoo me to MSE, I'm just starting to formally dig into real model theory)

Comment: @AlecRhea Yes, that's basically right. (Although I think more discussion of this should take place in a separate question, this comment thread is getting long.)

Comment: @NikWeaver: Why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 18):

Expositionally, forcing is (usually) easier to understand with a c.t.m. This **does indeed** lead to somewhat different results, such as

> $(*)\quad$ If there is a countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ then there is a countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH}$

as opposed to the snappier and more intuitive

> $(**)\quad$ If there is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ then there is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH}$

(which is of course equivalent to "$\mathsf{Con(ZFC)}\rightarrow\mathsf{Con(ZFC+\neg CH)}$" by the completeness theorem).

More precisely, thinking about c.t.m.s we see that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves $(*)$ but we do not immediately see that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves $(**)$.

---

There are, however, various ameliorating points here:

- First of all, $(*)$ is itself nontrivial; note that while the hypothesesized model is "special," so is the constructed model. So it's not really fair to say that it's *weaker* than $(**)$.
- More substantively, we could "stratify" forcing by finite subtheories of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. It turns out that we can write $\mathsf{ZFC}$ as a union of an increasing chain of finitely axiomatizable theories $\mathsf{ZFC}=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}T_i$ with the property that each $T_i$ "supports forcing" in the appropriate sense: if $\mathcal{M}$ is a c.t.m. of $T_i$ then each generic extension of $\mathcal{M}$ is again a model of $T_i$. *(And in fact this is overkill: it would be enough for our purposes to have each generic extension of a c.t.m. of $T_{i+1}$ satisfy $T_i$.)* The reflection principle gives us c.t.m.s of each $T_i$, forcing thenn gives *(for example)* c.t.m.s of each $T_i+\neg\mathsf{CH}$, and finally the finiteness of proofs lets us conclude $\mathsf{ZFC}\not\vdash\mathsf{CH}$. This is the approach Kunen outlines if memory serves, and we can think of it as also subsuming Nik Weaver's suggestion in the comments of introducing a named c.t.m. of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ "inside *(a conservative extension of)* the theory."
- We could also simply develop forcing over arbitrary *countable* models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Remember that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (and indeed much less) proves "If $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent then it has a countable model," so hypothesizing countable models - unlike countable *transitive* models - doesn't actually take us beyond the (obviously necessary) hypothesis of $\mathsf{Con(ZFC)}$. This may seem difficult due to the use of recursion in defining the structure $M[G]$ (let alone $\Vdash$) and the reference to $V$ in verifying Regularity in $M[G]$, but since the whole point is that the forcing relation is definable inside the "base structure" these issues are easily surmountable. In fact, via Boolean-valued models we can develop forcing over arbitrary models full stop. In my opinion, **this is the "right" approach to take** since it really gets at the model-theoretic heart of the matter.

Whichever approach one takes, the point is that the c.t.m.-related issues are not actually that substantive, and blithely assuming the existence of a c.t.m. - while technically improper - makes it easier to see the actual mathematical intricacies of forcing (namely, how the **combinatorial properties of the poset** correspond to the **logical properties of the extension** that results from forcing with that poset).

Comment: My experience (trying to learn from Kunen) was that being told to “blithely” or “naively” assume the existence of a ctm seemed condescending, felt out of place in an axiomatic study, and made me doubt the value of the intricacies in other parts of the proofs. It was a relief when I finally found Weaver’s respectful and clear approach.

Comment: @MattF. Fair enough, I suppose it will differ from person to person.

Comment: @MattF. I really appreciate your kind words. I feel I should say that this approach (summarized in a comment of mine above) is not original. I don't remember where I learned it, but I think someone told me once that it goes back to Shoenfield.

Comment: Also I should add that I found Noah's answer very illuminating.

Answer (score 3):

This is to slightly elaborate on point 2 of Noah Schweiber's answer, since in my opinion this approach is often presented in a somewhat confusing manner which ommits some key subtelties.

Forcing constructions, as usually presented indeed seem to imply only a result of the form: "If there exists a countable transitive model of ZFC, then there exists a countable transitive model of T."

However, the usual forcing arguments *can* be adapted to yield the result: "If ZFC is consistent, then T is consistent." There are several ways to do it, some of them were mentioned in other answers or comments, but let me focus on the "consistency of finite subtheories" approach.

We want to show consistency of $ZFC + \phi$ using forcing. The usual arguments show that for any theory $T \subset ZFC$ which contains some basic set theory and has a transitive model, $T + \phi$ has a transitive model.

Notice that we can present $ZFC$ as a union of finite theories $ZFC_n$. Let's say that each of the theories contains only formulae of complexity $\Sigma_{n+17}$ (since we want all fragments considered to be large enough to make sense).

*The "natural" argument works uniformly in $T$*, so actually $ZFC$ (or some modest fragments of arithmetic) proves that for any $n$ if $ZFC_n$ has a transitive model, then $ZFC_n + \phi$ has a model.

Moreover, and this is the key point, the *reflection principle* also works uniformly in $ZFC$, so $ZFC$ formally proves the following:
$$\forall M \Big[(M \models ZFC) \rightarrow \forall n (M \models \exists M'  \ M' \text{ is a transitive model of $\Sigma_n$-true sentences }) \Big].$$
(Notice where the quantification over $n$ is placed.)

Combining the two observations, we obtain:
$$ZFC \vdash \forall M \Big[ (M \models ZFC) \rightarrow \forall n (M \models \exists M' \ M' \text{ is a model of $\Sigma_n$-true sentences $+ \phi$}) \Big]$$.

Notice that $M'$ - a model of $ZFC_n$ within $M$, is in fact a model of $ZFC_n$ itself. So in particular, we get:
$$ZFC \vdash \Big[(\exists M \ M \models ZFC) \rightarrow \forall n (\exists M' \ M' \models ZFC_n + \phi)\Big]$$

When presented with the proof of the reflection principle, people often ask why cannot we just apply compactness. As a matter of fact, now we can do precisely this, once we have used the intermediate model to quantify over the fragments for which we apply the reflection argument. This yields:
$$ZFC \vdash \Big[(\exists M \ M \models ZFC) \rightarrow (\exists M' \ M' \models ZFC + \phi)\Big].$$

The last one is formally a statement that consistency of $ZFC$ implies consistency of some other theories, proved as a formal statement in our metatheory by meta-massaging the natural proof as usually given in textbook.

Comment: @MattF. Well, yes, but I want to stress the point, that given a model, ZFC is able to prove things about that very model. This would be either obscured or not expressed correctly, if I wanted to put all the statements with the existential statement in the precedent.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you review the beginning of Chapter VII. In page 185, Kunen wrote:

"The formal structure of our proof of Con(ZFC)$\rightarrow$ Con(ZFC+V$\neq$ L) will be as follows......"

I think that answers your question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).